# Unable to enter decimals in Android OS 4.2 and above

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

For HTML5 form, I have a field amount(input type number). When the user tries to enter a decimal (".") from soft keyboard on an Android 4.2 or above he is unable do so as the decimal is not displayed on soft keyboard.

Please suggest if any other input type needs to be used for entering a decimal value?

Comment: According to http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/ "number" is normally implemented as an adjustment widget not as a simple entry field, so you could try setting a fractional step value.  They also suggest for the iphone using a "text" field with a restricted input pattern, and that might work for you as well?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, mind writing that as a potential answer?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the material to turn it into a definitive answer without going through the exercise of building and trying it.  If you've been able to solve a closely related problem using the information at the link, how about you write up a nice explanatory answer/example based on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this issue...

I've tried in Nexus 5 Emulator and device running Android 4.2.2 (API level 17) and Android 4.4.2 (API level 19) respectively, and in both when using the following, the decimal point is displayed in the numerical keyboard.

```
<form>
    Amount: <input type="number">
</form>
```

[image]